# PHP Newsletter singup reverse engineer

Tags: php

I have the following code that someone before me setup for a newsletter signup system.

```
error_reporting(0);
set_magic_quotes_runtime (0);
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)
    $_POST[$k] = stripslashes($v);
foreach($_COOKIE as $k=>$v)
    $_COOKIE[$k] = stripslashes($v);
}

$msg = $_COOKIE['sb'.$_GET['id']];

$email = trim($_GET['email']);
$Ok = ereg("^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", $email);

$headers  = 'From: ' . $email . "\n"; 
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' ."\n"; 
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1' ."\n"; 
$headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'. "\n\n";

if ($Ok && ($msg != '')) {
mail($emailmanager,'Subscribe to Newsletter',$msg,$headers);
Header("Location: $urlok");
} else {
Header("Location: $urlko");
}
```

A php file is called by submitting the form (email address, name, state, phone number etc) which has this code:

```
error_reporting(0);

set_magic_quotes_runtime (0);
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)
    $_POST[$k] = stripslashes($v);
foreach($_COOKIE as $k=>$v)
    $_COOKIE[$k] = stripslashes($v);
}

$msg = '';
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {
if (strtolower($k) != "submit" && trim($v) != '')
    $msg .= "$k:$v\n";
}

$id = md5($msg);
setcookie("sb$id",$msg,time()+86400,'','',0);

$email = trim($_POST['email']);
```

It send an email to the person who filled in the form, with a link for them to click to verify their email address.

When they click the link, the first php file (at top) is called that then sends the stored details of the original form to an email address as a message, so the recipient of the email can manually enter these details into a database (mailing list).

I am trying to reverse engineer it so that, instead of sending a notification email to the mailing list manager, it inserts the details into a database.

I am pretty good with manipulating databases with php,but the above code is a bit beyond me.

I'm not sure how the code packs the details of all the inputs of the form into an id, stores until the email address is verified, then puts them all into the email sent to the list manager, but, looking at the code, can anyone see a way to extract those inputs out again, so that I can put them in some variables, ready to insert into my database table?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.
Cheers, Al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looping through the post data from the form when they clicked submit:

```
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)
    $_POST[$k] = stripslashes($v);
foreach($_COOKIE as $k=>$v)
    $_COOKIE[$k] = stripslashes($v);
}
```

The cookie is then sent as part of the e-mail message link for processing when they click it. You can just grab whatever data you want first time around from the $_POST data - perhaps flagging it as unvalidated or storing it in a temporary table and then validate it when they return.

Comment: Although I am now curious to know more about it, and would love to discover if it can be extracted in the second instance, your suggestion makes perfect sense, and to me seems the much more practical approach.

Thank you very much for your help.

All these damn trees, I new there was a forest around here somewhere.

Cheers, Al. (p.s. I would vote you up, but I only have a reputation of 10.)

Comment: No worries, not much of an answer, but glad it helped.

Comment: I'll vote the answer up, since is correctly points out that you don't really need to do more than grab data out of $_POST (and perhaps $_COOKIE). It's worth pointing out that the whole $msg logic near the bottom of the original code quote simply stuffs all of the $_POST data into a string, and assigns it to cookie with a name generated using the MD5 hash of the data itself. That's how the "persistence" works between page views.